# SQL to find inventory

Tags: sql, sqlite

I am very new to SQL and I have a the following situation:

- BTW, "qoh" = "quantity on hand"

1. product table:

| prod_code | qoh |
| --- | --- |
| 11QER/31 | 8 |
| 13-Q2/P2 | 32 |
| 14-Q1/L3 | 18 |
| 1546-QQ2 | 15 |
| 1558-QW1 | 23 |
| 2232/QTY | 8 |
| 2232/QWE | 6 |
| 2238/QPD | 12 |
| 23109-HB | 23 |
| 23114-AA | 8 |
| 54778-2T | 43 |
| 89-WRE-Q | 11 |
| PVC23DRT | 188 |
| SM-18277 | 172 |
| SW-23116 | 237 |
| WR3/TT3 | 18 |

2. invoiced detail table:

| prod_code | quantity-sold |
| --- | --- |
| 13-Q2/P2 | 1 |
| 23109-HB | 1 |
| 54778-2T | 2 |
| 2238/QPD | 1 |
| 1546-QQ2 | 1 |
| 13-Q2/P2 | 5 |
| 54778-2T | 3 |
| 23109-HB | 2 |
| PVC23DRT | 12 |
| SM-18277 | 3 |
| 2232/QTY | 1 |
| 23109-HB | 1 |
| 89-WRE-Q | 1 |
| 13-Q2/P2 | 2 |
| 54778-2T | 1 |
| PVC23DRT | 5 |
| WR3/TT3 | 3 |
| 23109-HB | 1 |

I want to write a SQL to find out the current inventory, QOH in the product table minus the related item quantity-sold:

| prod_code | quantity-sold |
| --- | --- |
| 13-Q2/P2 | 0 (8 - 1 - 5 -2) |
| 54778-2T | 37 (43 - 2 - 3 - 1) |

I tried to use join tables etc and the results did not come out right.

How to write the SQL?

Much appreciated!

Philip

Comment: "I tried to use join tables etc and the results did not come out right." - please the queries that you tried

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A correlated subquery is a simple what to write this:

```
select p.*,
       p.qoh - (select coalesce(sum(id.quantity_sold), 0)
                from invoice_detail id
                where id.prod_code = p.prod_code
               ) as current_inventory
from product p;
```

It is not clear why your result set has only two products.  This version would include all products.  And with in index on `invoice_detail(prod_code, quantity_sold)` should be the fastest method to do what you want.

Comment: I was just give two sample lines in the question...

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
    product.prod_code,
    prod_code.qoh,
    COALESCE( qtySold.total_sold, 0 ) AS qty_sold,
    ( prod_code.qoh - COALESCE( qtySold.total_sold, 0 ) ) AS current_inventory
FROM
    product
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
    (
        SELECT
            prod_code,
            SUM( quantity_sold ) AS total_sold
        FROM
            invoiced_detail
        GROUP BY
            prod_code
    ) AS qtySold ON
        product.prod_code = qtySold.prod_code
ORDER BY
    product.prod_code
```

Answer (score 1):

A **left join** may be used if you summarized the total quantity sold first and used this as a subquery to join on. See example with your sample data below:

### Example

**Schema (SQLite v3.30)**

```
CREATE TABLE products (
  `prod_code` VARCHAR(8),
  `qoh` INTEGER
);

INSERT INTO products
  (`prod_code`, `qoh`)
VALUES
  ('11QER/31', '8'),
  ('13-Q2/P2', '32'),
  ('14-Q1/L3', '18'),
  ('1546-QQ2', '15'),
  ('1558-QW1', '23'),
  ('2232/QTY', '8'),
  ('2232/QWE', '6'),
  ('2238/QPD', '12'),
  ('23109-HB', '23'),
  ('23114-AA', '8'),
  ('54778-2T', '43'),
  ('89-WRE-Q', '11'),
  ('PVC23DRT', '188'),
  ('SM-18277', '172'),
  ('SW-23116', '237'),
  ('WR3/TT3', '18');

CREATE TABLE invoice_details (
  `prod_code` VARCHAR(8),
  `quantity-sold` INTEGER
);

INSERT INTO invoice_details
  (`prod_code`, `quantity-sold`)
VALUES
  ('13-Q2/P2', '1'),
  ('23109-HB', '1'),
  ('54778-2T', '2'),
  ('2238/QPD', '1'),
  ('1546-QQ2', '1'),
  ('13-Q2/P2', '5'),
  ('54778-2T', '3'),
  ('23109-HB', '2'),
  ('PVC23DRT', '12'),
  ('SM-18277', '3'),
  ('2232/QTY', '1'),
  ('23109-HB', '1'),
  ('89-WRE-Q', '1'),
  ('13-Q2/P2', '2'),
  ('54778-2T', '1'),
  ('PVC23DRT', '5'),
  ('WR3/TT3', '3'),
  ('23109-HB', '1');
```

---

**Query #1**

```
SELECT 
    p.prod_code,
    p.qoh - IFNULL( t1.total_quantity_sold,0) as current_inventory
FROM 
    products p
LEFT JOIN
(SELECT
    id.`prod_code`, 
    sum(id.`quantity-sold`) as total_quantity_sold
FROM
    invoice_details id 
GROUP BY
   id.prod_code
) t1 ON p.prod_code = t1.prod_code;
```

| prod_code | current_inventory |
| --- | --- |
| 11QER/31 | 8 |
| 13-Q2/P2 | 24 |
| 14-Q1/L3 | 18 |
| 1546-QQ2 | 14 |
| 1558-QW1 | 23 |
| 2232/QTY | 7 |
| 2232/QWE | 6 |
| 2238/QPD | 11 |
| 23109-HB | 18 |
| 23114-AA | 8 |
| 54778-2T | 37 |
| 89-WRE-Q | 10 |
| PVC23DRT | 171 |
| SM-18277 | 169 |
| SW-23116 | 237 |
| WR3/TT3 | 15 |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/jdkKJcKENTtyeGtv4YzMjW/1)